# VBA - Excel through macros for each row in a column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am working on developing a tool that would allow me to call about 15 subs to take text from a cell, analyze it, and then generate a letter for it. Now I haven't worked with loops much but I wanted to see if my thinking on this is right or if there is advice on how to make it better:

```
    Sub Loop_Process()
Dim myrange as string
myrange = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address

For each i in Range(myrange).Rows
Call Macro 1
Call Macro 2
'etc

Next i
End sub
```

Would that work to funnel through the whole list? Any major pitfalls that you can think of? The other thing I need to figure out is that it saves PDFs with the contents of the Cell it is running the macro on as the title, If the save PDF macro is within the Loop, how could I get it to reference the cell. Does that make sense? Thank you for the help!!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells

Comment: `For Each i`. This is rather unsightly. `i` as a variable is usually used in a `For` loop, not a `For Each` loop.

Comment: Btw, `Range(myrange)` is a single cell.

Comment: @BigBen I thought that would search all rows in column a and end at the bottom of the data to get the selection. Am I doing that wrong?

Comment: Yes, `myrange` is the address of the very last populated cell in column A. Use `Debug.Print myrange` and inspect the output in the Immediate Window, if it's helpful.

Comment: So that should be ```For each i in Range("A1:"myrange).Rows``` is that right?

Also @BigBen is there a different way I should interact with For Each rather than i? I am super open to feedback, I am pretty new to this.

Comment: @braX So I had looked at that, but it didn't really address defining a dynamic range as the data is not always the same quantity.

Comment: `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in Range("A1:A" & lastRow)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help on that, that makes a lot of sense. Any ideas on this part:
"The other thing I need to figure out is that it saves PDFs with the contents of the Cell it is running the macro on as the title, If the save PDF macro is within the Loop, how could I get it to reference the cell that the macros are running based on?"

Comment: You need to add a `Range` parameter to whatever subroutine creates the PDFs.

Comment: @BigBen so I do that with:
```Dim AccountNumber as String
AccountNumber = Right(ws.Range("A2").Value, 3)
   dt = Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy hh mm")
    fName = EXPORTS & "AccountEnding" & AccountNumber & " - Created On - "

    If Len(Dir(fName & ".pdf")) > 0 Then sep = " - "
    fName = fName & sep & dt & ".pdf"```

But I dont know how to get that "A2" to move with the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to take text from each cell you reference and use it within your 15 other procedures.

As @BigBen said - you need to reference the start and end cell of your range.  At the moment you're just looking at the last cell.

This code will go through each cell in the range and pass it to a macro.  It also demonstrates the [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) code block which helps simplify the code syntax.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim myRange As Range
    
    'Always be specific which workbook and sheet your range is on.
    'The overall range and the start/end cells are fully qualified:
    'Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range( _
    '                 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), _
    '                 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
                  
    'The above row shortened using the With...End With block.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In myRange.Cells
        Macro1 myCell 'Pass the cell reference to the Macro1 procedure.
    Next myCell
    
End Sub

Public Sub Macro1(CellRef As Range)

    With CellRef
        MsgBox "Row:  " & .Row & vbCr & _
               "Col:" & Split(.Address, "$")(1) & vbCr & _
               "Val: " & .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Darren thank you so much for the help! I THINK I understand this, but I have a couple of follow up questions. Within my macro because of:

``` Macro1 MyCell``` 

Does this mean that I can just reference that as a string with no DIM for it in the macro?

Also I don't understand the CellRef information. Is that for referencing it to fill a cell within another sheet?

I also uncovered that I would like the loop to return a result to the adjacent cell. So for example, if F9 is an account with data, I want G9 to say yes. If F10 does not have data, G10 would return no. Thank you for help

Comment: `myCell` will reference each cell within `myRange` in turn.  I declare it with a DIM just before the loop.  Don't consider it a string - it's a reference to a cell on the worksheet so contains the address, value, formatting and everything else to do with that cell.  The `myCell` variable is passed to the `Macro1` procedure where it is called `CellRef` - I then pull the value, row and address from the variable. `myCell` and `CellRef` can be considered the same variable in this case.

Comment: You can update the adjacent cell to `myCell` by using `myCell.Offset(,1)=`  for next column or `myCell.Offset(1)` for next row.  To update it from within `Macro1` you'd use `CellRef.Offset(,1)=`

Comment: Hey I have it running, and it seems to not recognize the ```cellref``` within the sub macro. In trying to send this as a string to another application it causes an error:
```Sess0.SendKeys ("LTXN ") & Range("CellRef").Value```

The header of that sub is ```Public Sub AccountEligible(CellRef As Range)```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Sending it to another application?  Which one?  If it's one of the MS Office apps then it should be fairly easy - anything else and you'll have to look at the documentation for that app.  It does look like you're passing it to another procedure within Excel - `Public Sub AccountEligible(CellRef As Range)` in which case you'd call that with `AccountEligible CellRef` if done from within `Macro1` or `AccountEligible myCell` if done from within the `Test` procedure.

Comment: I am sending it to Attachmate Extra. Which all of those work, but what is confusing me is passing values around between macros. Because should the Account Eligible sub create two values that are passed back into the other macro?? Sorry I am so dense here. If you have a dummies resource to point me to on this then I can totally go to that so I stop wasting your time.